# What's the proper way to garbage collect?

Tags: javascript, typescript, memory-management, garbage-collection

I have some TypeScript code where a variable is of a certain type and can't be assigned `null` nor `undefined`. If I want to reset its value, so that the previous one can be garbage collected, would it make sense to force it to `undefined` rather than an empty object, which is memory allocated for nothing?

```js
type SomeType = { someProp?: number };

type MyType = { myProp: SomeType };

let variable: MyType = { myProp: { someProp: 5 } };

// What's the proper way to garbage collect?

// This
variable = { myProp: {} };

// Or this?
variable = {} as MyType;

// Or this?
variable = undefined as unknown as MyType;
```

Comment: 99% of the time, the proper way is to just *not worry about it* and let the engine handle it automatically once the identifier is no longer in scope anywhere. I guess you could assign `undefined` or `null`, but that makes the code ugly and will make the code confusing for (almost certainly) no benefit.

Comment: @CertainPerformance but if for example `myProp` has three required properties being arrays, should I allocate an object containing three arrays, or force an empty object (force because in theory the empty arrays are required as per typing)

Comment: Neither IMO, I wouldn't bother with trying to force GC at all

Comment: All right, I get it. Just don't worry about it. Thank you very much for your wisdom.

Comment: What [@CertainPerformance said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72252404/whats-the-proper-way-to-garbage-collect#comment127651648_72252404) is true, but it is important to note that as long as the identifier **is** in scope, its associated value will **not** be garbage collected. If the `variable` is in scope for your entire program, and you want to make its value eligible for gc, you should set its value to something nullish (`undefined`/`null`). This is almost **always** unnecessary except in the case that the previous value is **MASSIVE** in terms of memory required.

Comment: @jsejcksn I don't have enough reputation to upvote your comment, but thank you!